# How many three-digit even numbers can be formed by using the digits $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ if repetition of digits is not permitted?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many three-digit even numbers can be formed by using the digits $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ if repetition of digits is not permitted?

Initial thoughts:
The ones place can only be even so the digits we will be selected will be $\{0,2,4,6\}=$ total of $4$ digits.  The second priority is given to the hundreds place as $0$ can't really be selected, so total number of digits gets restricted to $5$ digits.  And last priority is given to the ten's place so the total number of choices gets restricted  to $6$ digits.  So the total number of ways $=6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4=120$.
These are my conclusions.
Please correct me.

Comment: Note that it makes a difference if the last digit is $0$ or one of $\{2,4,6\}$.  I suggest separating that case off.  And the part about the tens place doesn't make sense.

Comment: But if the last digit is a $0$, you still have 6 choices for the hundred's digit. And I can't see how you conclude that there are 6 possibilities for the ten's digit.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is along the right lines, but there are some small corrections.

First, assume that the ones place has a 0. Then, the hundreds place can have any of {1,2,3,4,5,6}, so there are six choices. Following this, the tens place can have any of the remaining five.

Next, assume the ones place has a 2, 4, or 6. Now, the hundreds place has five choices, since both 0 and one more number are removed. Finally, for the tens place, two options have been removed: the one in the ones place, and the one in the tens place. Thus, there are five remaining options.

So in total, we get $6\cdot 5 + 3\cdot (5\cdot 5) = 105$ options.

Comment: What is the intuition behind these kind of problems?
is there a general abstract idea/concept to it?
or is this problem just a concrete one?

Comment: I would say that the general idea here is simply counting the number of number of permutations without repetition. The special structure that arises from the fact that 0 is not allowed to be the hundreds digit seems to just be a more concrete example, I am not sure if there is any more general idea behind this

Answer (score 0):

CASE I: if the last digit(units) is even but $0$ may in hundreds digit then the number of arrangements : $6\times 5\times 4=120$

CASE II: if the last digit is even and $0$ is the first(hundreds) digit then the number of arrangements:$1\times 5\times 3=15$

the number of $3$-digit even numbers without repetition is $120-15=105$